# How to filter script output in bash using a query like "(me OR you) OR (john AND ! doe)"?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I'd like to be able to pass any command line output to a bash script or some command line program that filters the content depending on a boolean search - regular expressions are not required (but it's ok if they're supported)

For example, if I had a file like so:

#### file1.txt

```
hello there
me and you are going to the store
this is a file created by john doe and his friend jane
john is here
```

then running my fictional script could be done like so:

```
$ cat file1.txt | filter "(me OR you) OR (john AND ! doe)"
me and you are going to the store
john is here
```

I could probably cobble something together like a bunch of `grep` and `grep -v` calls, but wonder if I'm missing some more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more complex filters like this, `awk` might do the job:

```
awk '( /me|you/ ) || (/john/ && ! /doe/ )' /path/to/file
```

Comment: sweet! that's way better than i expected... I haven't used awk tons (just for selecting a column from output mostly), but this is great... much appreciated!